# EditText multi line doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I want the user to be able to press the return or enter key on the keyboard to make a new line. I'm testing this on a Samsung Galaxy S3, and the return key is there, but it behaves like it is a dead button. You can keep on clicking and clicking but to no effect. I've tried removing the input type as well, and adding single line to false, but none of them create what I want to achieve.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/carrotCake"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Enter your recipe..." >
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `android:imeOptions="actionNone"`. Also note that you probably want `android:gravity="left|top"`:

Comment: Hmm... still get the same problem. The return key is there, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @EGHDK: Works for me here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Basic/Field

Comment: Thanks, I will step through my code, as it's probably an error in there rather than my xml.